# XMLHttpRequest is not sending POST data to Django server

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-views

Javascript to send data via XMLHttpRequest

```
csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken'); 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/register');
request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken); 
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"); 
request.send("data");
```

Django view:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        print("django server")
        print(request.POST)
```

Sever is printing:

```
django server
<QueryDict: {}>
```

I have also triend application/json as content type with json data, but that is also not working. The data does not seem to be being passed to the server. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you show your `urls.py` file?

Comment: @funnydman I eventually figured this out. Posting answer now if you're curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The request actually was being sent. This is how to access data:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.body) # this would print "data"
```

In order for print(request.POST) to work the Content-Type must be 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def register_user(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        status = "1"
    else:
        status = "0"
    return HttpResponse(status)
```

Comment: The issue is that the request is not sending any parameters. It is making a successful request however.